# subsonic 3.0 , The SqlServer default value doesn't work?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, subsonic, subsonic3

I used subsonic 3 with T4,It's very simple to use.But I get a problem now.I specify the default value in the sqlserver 2005.Then I called save() method in subsonic.I found the default value doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Default values won't work on inserts because your object will set the value first - whether it's null or ... whatever. The answer here is to set the default on the object.